# Flash attributes in Spring MVC 3.1 not visible to redirected JSP

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-mvc, post-redirect-get

I am using Spring 3.1's new Flash Attribute support to set flash attributes on a `RedirectAttributes` object in a Controller and then invoking a redirect. That redirect request is in turn caught by a filter which then sends it on its merry way to the JSP that it's intended for. The problem: I can't see the flash attributes either from within the filter's `doFilter()` method or from the JSP. Non-flash (URL) attributes make it just fine.

Controller that does the redirect:

```
@RequestMapping("/pages/login")
public String login (HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    model.put("userId", "batman");
    String redirectUrl = request.getParameter("redirectUrl");
    if (redirectUrl != null) {
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("attr1","ababab");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashAttr1", "flashflash");
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = model.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(key, model.get(key));
        }
        return "redirect:"+redirectUrl;
    } else {
        return "pages/login";
    }
}
```

The filter which picks up the redirect doesn't do anything interesting in this case:

```
public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    //if (httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("userId") == null) {
    //...do some stuff here which invokes controller above as well as the redirect
    //} else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    //}
}
```

The page that gets redirected to following the filter:

```
...
<title>Test Web App 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Flash attribute: <c:out value="${flashAttr1}"/></p>
<p>Welcome <c:out value="${userId}"/>!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Neither `flashAttr1` nor `userId` end up being populated in the page. The `attr1` non-flash attribute the controller set does appear in the URL params of the page, so that seems to work.

Here is some output from `log4j` after I set `springfamework.web` to DEBUG:

```
19:15:44,406 DEBUG http-8080-1 view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:494 - Returni
ng redirect view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: name 'redir
ect:http://my_hostname:8080/test-webapp-1/protected/protected_page.jsp';
URL [http://my_hostname:8080/test-webapp-1/protected/protected_page.jsp]]
19:15:44,406 DEBUG http-8080-1 servlet.DispatcherServlet:1155 - 
Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: name
'redirect:http://my_hostname:8080/test-webapp-1/protected/protected_page.jsp';
URL [http://my_hostname:8080/test-webapp-1/protected/protected_page.jsp]] in
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
19:15:44,421 DEBUG http-8080-1 support.DefaultFlashMapManager:199 - Saving Flash
Map=[Attributes={userId=batman, flashAttr1=flashflash}, targetRequestPath=/test-
webapp-1/protected/protected_page.jsp, targetRequestParams={attr1=[ababab]}]
19:15:44,421 DEBUG http-8080-1 servlet.DispatcherServlet:913 - Successfully comp
leted request
```

Following a brief stop at the filter I've shown above, I am taken to the page with URL

```
http://my_hostname:8080/test-webapp-1/protected/protected_page.jsp?attr1=ababab
```

But neither of the attributes I expect that JSP to find are displayed. I have also debugged through the `doFilter()` method shown above and failed to find the flash attributes in the request's session.

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong at this point. Everything works as expected except for those flash attributes. If there is anything else I should provide to make the situation more clear, I will be happy to.

Comment: And of course I have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` set (along with the property to not set model attributes as URL params) :-)

Comment: Can you remove the filter and see ?

Comment: After thinking on this a bit, I believe the core of the issue stems from the fact that there is indeed a Redirect involved here, which means there are two HTTP sessions in play. Naturally adding attributes to one will have no effect on the other. So there isn't really any way to "fix" this approach per se; rather, I have to think of another approach to get attributes over from the Controller to a page in another domain but not do it through URL query params...

Comment: Read this: http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this issue a few months ago with AJAX-related redirects.  If you use a read-only HTTP POST pattern, you can specify a [`@ResponseStatus`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html) to *simulate* a POST.  Also be sure to have your method return a `View` or `ModelAndView` (as opposed to `String`) so that Spring knows to look up the Flash scope for the given `@RequestMapping`.

Pseudocode:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public ModelAndView login (...) {
    ...
}
```